# Received errors when using self in a function that has another from another self

Tags: python, class, object, self

I wanted to use the values for self.value which I have initiated in function "take" inside the function of "func1". However, I received an error when trying to do so.

code:

```
class all():
    def __init__(self):
        self.temp = self.value # Here I declare it first before the self.new but still get error. May I know why?
        if:
            **func**
        else:
            **func**
        self.new = self.func1()

    def func1(self):
        **func**
        return ["{}".format(self.temp)]

    def take(value):
#In this example, the value already contained some values. and already been called. but in another program not in the same program.
        self.value = value
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: "all" object has no attribute "value"
```

Comment: You have to *call* `take` if you want `self.value` to be created...

Comment: You probably shouldn't call your class `all`, since [that is the name of a built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

Comment: But I have already called take. Its still giving me the same error

Answer (score 1):

the reason of behind the occurs this error, you didn't define the value in the constructor(**init**) method.

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 20(example purpose)
```

Comment: Im sorry for confusing but I have already defined the value before by calling it in another program. It has already stored with values.

Comment: I know but it's not declare into the contructor so that the reason you got the error.

Comment: But I also tried to put it in __init__ such as  self.value = self.temp and inside the take function: self.temp = value. Still receive the same error.

Comment: you need to access self.temp = self.value instead of self.temp = value.

Comment: So do you mean inside the __init__ I should put first self.temp=self.value. then in the func1 is return ["{}".format(self.temp)]? This still get the same error. this time it says, there is no value(self.value) for line inside __init__

Comment: you need to declare the self.value in init method as I gave you answer your question. if you will not declare the variable you will get the error.

Comment: Sir, I have updated my post, could you please check. I follow your instruction to declare the self.value in init method but still getting the same error

Comment: you didn't do the declare self.value in init method, kindly add code into the init method something like this self.value = 20 # example.

Comment: Sir, if possible, please tell me into which line should I add?

Comment: your final code may be something like this.

class all:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.value = 20 # example purpose
        self.temp = self.value
        self.func1()

    def func1(self):
        self.take(self.value)
        return ["{}".format(self.value)]

    def take(self, value):
        self.value = value


all = all()

Please arrage the code.

Comment: I tried another method and it works, I just move the "self.new = self.func1()" into take function after self.value = value.